# Django no conecta con servidor postgres

Tags: base-de-datos, django, postgresql

Monté mi aplicación de Django en un servidor a traves de cPanel siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffqMZ5IcmSY) pero por alguna razon me está dando error para conectarse a la base de datos de PostgreSQL. Me retorna este error:

```
OperationalError at /sales/
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "usuariodb", database "ddbb_prueba", SSL off
```

Esta es mi configuración en el `settings.py` de la base de datos:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'HOST': 'server.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Password',
    }
}
```

El servidor está corriendo con la versión Django `3.0.4` y la versión de Python `3.7.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es tan simple que me costó trabajo dar con la solución. Los servidores de base de datos y web, por lo general, estan montados en el mismo sitio, por lo que el servidor de PostgreSQL viene configurado para que no acepte peticiones externas para evitar posibles ataques, por lo que es tan sencillo que hacer la petición por `localhost`. Así quedaría la configuración del `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Password',
    }
}
```